# How to detect string end position in mql4?

Tags: string, substring, mql4

Im trying to figure out how to find the end of a string. I'm able to get to the first number in the string that i want (the 6), but I cant figure out how count to the end of the string `</td>`.My thought is if i can figure how how far it is from the 6 to the closing bracket,I can then substring to get the number 6586.97. Is that correct thinking?

example string   `<td>6586.97 Lots</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringFind()` to detect start of the message that starts with ">" and end of the message (space bar) and do not forget to start looking for end after start. `StringSubstr()` is to cut the string that you need

```
string getStringFromTag(const string example){
    int starts = StringFind(example,">");
    if(starts>0){
       int ends = StringFind(example," ",starts+1);
       if(ends>0){
          string result=StringSubstr(starts+1,ends-starts-1);
             return result;
       }
    }
    return NULL;}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  Please explain your answer and how it solves the question.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, thank you for your reply.  This is what i love about coding. There are a number of ways to get the job done. I had come up with a solution late last night and will post it here.

```
 Count=0;
     for (int i =0 ; i<20; i++){
     VOL1=StringSubstr(data,string_pos+112+i+string_length,1);
        if(VOL1!="/")Count++;
           else{Answer=StringSubstr(data,string_pos+112+string_length,Count-6);}}
     return(Answer);
```

What i did was, starting at the 6 i just kept moving to the right till i found the forward slash. Then StringSubstr back.